# Counting operations in Azure Monitor Log Analytics query

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I want to query operations like Add-MailboxPermission with FullAccess and deleted emails/calendar events to find compromised accounts (in 30m intervals). 
1. How I should modify my code to show operations which fulfil both assumptions at the same time (if I change "or" to "and" then it will check both assumptions in one log)? 
2. How can I modify a "count" to decrease the number of logs only to this which show min 10 in the result? Maybe there should be another function?

```
OfficeActivity
| where parse_json(Parameters)[2].Value like "FullAccess" or Operation contains "Delete" 
| summarize Events=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 30m), Operation, UserId
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

1. Yes, the logical `and` operator returns true only if both conditions are `true`. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/logicaloperators) doc for the query language reference.
2. Yes again, there is the [top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/topoperator) operator that's used to return the first N records sorted by the specified columns, used as follows:

   ```
   OfficeActivity
   | where parse_json(Parameters)[2].Value like "FullAccess" and Operation contains "Delete" 
   | summarize Events=count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 30m), Operation, UserId
   | top 10 by Events asc
   ```

**Additional tip:**
There are `limit` and `take` operators as well that return resultset up to the specified number of rows, but with a caveat that there is no guarantee as to which records are returned, unless the source data is sorted.

Hope this helps!